# Float* or Vector in Boost shared structure

Tags: boost, vector, shared-memory

I have following code which writes the structure to boost shared memory. I am not able to add new float* or Vector. boost version:1.59.0 Getting bunch of errors as

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::interprocess::allocator<boost::container::container_detail::list_node<fl‌​oat, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>......."
```

Tried:

```
typedef boost::interprocess::list<float, salloc::rebind<float>::other> shared_float;
```

Any suggestions how to add float* or vectors in structure which will be added to boost shared memory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;


struct InData;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<InData, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> salloc;
typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, salloc::rebind<char>::other> shared_string;

struct InData {
    int X, Y, H, W;

    InData(salloc alloc) : Label(alloc) {}
    shared_string Label;
};

int main() {

    std::cout << "Using Boost "
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minor version
              << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
              << std::endl;

    shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
    managed_shared_memory managed_shm(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 10000);

    salloc alloc_inst(managed_shm.get_segment_manager());

    InData tData(alloc_inst); // = managed_shm.construct<InData>("InDataStructure")();

    tData.Label = "Hello World";
    tData.H = 1;
    tData.W = 1;
    tData.Y = 1;
    tData.X = 1;

    typedef boost::interprocess::list<InData, salloc> MyList;
    MyList *myvector = managed_shm.construct<MyList>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);

    myvector->push_back(tData);
}
```

Comment: You can't abbreviate the error there. The error says "error: no matching function for call to X" and you manage to put less than the interesting half of "X"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles, and looks like it what you want:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44332f2a1a5e4d1f)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;


struct InData;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<InData, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> salloc;
typedef boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, salloc::rebind<char>::other> shared_string;
typedef boost::interprocess::vector<float, salloc::rebind<float>::other> shared_float_vec;

struct InData {
    int X, Y, H, W;

    InData(salloc alloc) : Label(alloc), Floats(alloc) {}
    shared_string Label;
    shared_float_vec Floats;
};

int main() {

    std::cout << "Using Boost "
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minor version
              << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
              << std::endl;

    shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
    managed_shared_memory managed_shm(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 10000);

    salloc alloc_inst(managed_shm.get_segment_manager());

    InData tData(alloc_inst); // = managed_shm.construct<InData>("InDataStructure")();

    tData.Label = "Hello World";
    tData.Floats.push_back(3.14);
    tData.H = 1;
    tData.W = 1;
    tData.Y = 1;
    tData.X = 1;

    typedef boost::interprocess::list<InData, salloc> MyList;
    MyList *myvector = managed_shm.construct<MyList>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);

    myvector->push_back(tData);
}
```